# ui4j how to handle scroll in headless mode

Tags: java, ui4j

I am using ui4j library to scape a website, and a button click by emolument.click(), I am getting the following exception:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl.getThumb(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl.thumbPosition(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:284)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl.getThumbPosition(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:380)

There is a stack overflow post about it, it was solved by page.show(), but since my application is running at headless mode as a background process, I don't have luxury to take on page.show(), I am wondering if possible:
1. catch the scroll event, and ignore it, how?
2. during launching, can I specify the webview reasonable big enough to avoid scrolling? I don't see this option from api.